# Displaying subtitles using AVPlayerViewController with swift

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, tvos, subtitle, avplayerviewcontroller

I am new to Swift and video streaming. I am trying to play videos in AppleTV. 
Did some one try to add subtitles with AVPlayerViewController in swift from an external srt file. I am trying to do the same using code from here: https://github.com/mhergon/MPMoviePlayerController-Subtitles.

I changed the code to suit my requirements, but it is throwing an exception:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
>   Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
>   H:|-(20)-[l]-(20)-|

At this point in the Subtitles.swift file:

```
var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(20)-[l]-(20)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["l" : subtitleLabel!])
    subtitleContainer?.addConstraints(constraints)
```

Comment: Can you show config your view on storyboard or xib? Or list element view you set in code?

Answer (score 0):

The error message complains, that there is no superview. Looking at the source I would assume that the container is not properly set. This leads to `subtitleLabel` not being child of a super view and that makes the constraint fail.

Comment: Yes you are right container is not being set in getContainer(). I am not sure why this not set. I don't understand how that c.tag == 1006 is true when using MPMoviePlayerController and not when using AVPLayerViewController.

Comment: @Enmud Can you show your code which sets up your views?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this below code subtitle container is being set. But i didn't find anywhere the tag which is referred in the below code. You can check the same code in github repository (Link in question) .    private func getContainer() { 
        for a in view.subviews {
            for b in a.subviews {
                for c in b.subviews {
                    if c.tag == 1006 {
                        subtitleContainer = c
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }

Comment: @Enmud Did you set the tag to 1006 for the view which shall be the container view? I assume that an xib file or a storyboard and in there you likely need to mark a view as the container view. The github code seems to expect that the container view has a tag value of 1006.

Comment: I didn't set this also I am sure that there is no view with tag 1006. But surprisingly the container is set in the original code from repository and shows subtitles.  I am confused. You can debug original repository code where this is set.